# Call unlock on std::shared_mutex that is locked in shared mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, mutex

C++17 introduces the [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) type. I have been looking at the documentation over on [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) with a particular interest for cases that produce undefined behavior.

While reading through both unlock methods (one for releasing exclusive ownership, one for releasing shared ownership), I've noticed the documentation is a little vague on one occasion.

For [`std::shared_mutex::unlock_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex/unlock_shared), the documentation states (emphasis mine):

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution in **shared mode**, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

It is clearly indicated that a call to `unlock_shared` must be preceded by a call to `lock_shared` as that is the only way to lock the mutex in shared mode.

For [`std::shared_mutex::unlock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex/unlock), the documentation states:

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

There is no mention of the level of access the current thread of execution must hold before calling `unlock`. This made me wonder if it is also capable of releasing shared ownership as well as exclusive ownership.

**My question:** is it undefined behavior to release shared ownership of a `std::shared_mutex` with a call to `unlock` instead of `unlock_shared`?

If possible, I'd like a quote from the C++ standard that explicitly confirms or denies undefined behavior in the aforementioned scenario.

Comment: Why have two different functions if one of them always works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [[thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex.requirements.mutex) we have

> The expression `m.unlock()` shall be well-formed and have the following semantics:
>
> *Requires*: The calling thread shall own the mutex.
>
> *Effects*: Releases the calling thread's ownership of the mutex.
>
> *Return* type: void.
>
> *Synchronization*: This operation synchronizes with subsequent lock operations that obtain ownership on the same object.
>
> *Throws*: Nothing.

So, as long as the thread owns the mutex ,whether it is in shared mode or not, `unlock` will release the threads ownership of the mutex.

Comment: @skypjack The requirements apply *The mutex types are the standard library types mutex, recursive_­mutex, timed_­mutex, recursive_­timed_­mutex, shared_­mutex, and shared_­timed_­mutex. They shall meet the requirements set out in this section. In this description, m denotes an object of a mutex type.* ([source](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex.requirements#mutex-1))

Comment: Oh, I see. So the second part is (let me say) _an integration_ of the requirements you linked. It makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @skypjack What that section says is that a call to `m.lock_­shared()` will synchronize to the last call of `m.unlock()`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Really appreciated you spent the time to explain it.

Comment: @skypjack No problem.  Reading the standard can be.. daunting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would the incentive be of having a separate `unlock_shared` if the normal `unlock` covers both levels of ownership? After all, shared mutex types must always adhere to the requirements of mutex types and thus will always have the `unlock` available. I cannot think of any other reason besides allowing implementations to better optimize `lock_shared` as it is guaranteed to be preceded by a `lock_shared` only.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis I'm not sure why it is there except maybe to make it a complete pair.  I'm having trouble trying to find a design decision about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver If this is not mentioned in the standard, this is most likely a defect. I am sure it was not the intention to allow using `unlock` with `lock_shared`. At least on Windows where `std::mutex` is based on `SRWLOCK` this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't go through the standard to verify what exactly it says, but [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#shared_mutex_rationale) clearly states that `lock`/`unlock` and `lock_shared`/`unlock_shared` calls should be paired:

```
shared_mutex  | Semantics
--------------+---------------------------------------------
lock          | Lock the mutex in unique ownership mode
unlock        | unlock the mutex from unique ownership mode
lock_shared   | Lock the mutex in shared ownership mode
unlock_shared | unlock the mutex from shared ownership mode
```

It also explicitly states that this separation exists because of how [`SRWLOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx) is implemented on Windows:

> Additionally, some operating systems (e.g. Windows) have different
>   names for unlocking shared vs unlocking unique as well. Use of
>   different names in the C++ API allows for a more efficient binding to
>   such OS API's.

If standard does not mention this somewhere explicitly, it is most likely a defect in the standard. Regardless of where this was intentional, in practice all `shared_mutex` implementations shipped with MSVC on Windows will not work like that as they *require* pairing lock-unlock calls properly.

On POSIX systems both `unlock` and `unlock_shared` are indeed mapped to a single function `pthread_rwlock_unlock`, so both are most likely to be equivalent there. This is a side effect that should not be relied upon.

---

On Windows 7 `SRWLOCK` uses the least significant bit to mark lock as locked by either reader or writer. Function `unlock` clears that bit, corrupting the lock, while `unlock_shared` only clears it if the last reader leaves the lock. Following example shows how the lock changes its state:

```
mtx.lock_shared(); // 0x11 - 1 reader, locked (shared)
mtx.lock_shared(); // 0x21 - 2 readers, locked (shared)
mtx.unlock();      // 0x20 - 2 readers, unlocked (invalid state)
mtx.lock();        // 0x21 - 2 readers, locked (shared)
```

Final `lock` is able to acquire the mutex even through there is another reader holding the lock. After that `std::shared_mutex` is considered to be locked by 2 readers, so more readers can enter the lock. So in the sequence above `lock` has locked the mutex in shared ownership mode, instead of exclusive as a side effect of misusage.

Comment: Regarding your MSVC remark. Our company uses Visual C++ 2015 tools;  I was experimenting with multiple threads pairing `lock_shared` with `unlock` at the time I asked this question. As you predicted, nasty stuff happened at runtime (exceptions and such). We are planning on switching to Visual C++ 2017 soon, the guy responsible for making our codebase compatible with these tools has notified me that the same experiment works just fine when compiled with the new compiler version.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Visual Studio 2017 uses the same runtime as Visual Studio 2015 (they didn't change it like they usually do), so both are binary compatible. Plus, I doubt they would change their implementation - they have nothing to substitute it with. It should use the same SRWLOCK.

Comment: Hmmm, just your answer made me already doubt that changing versions would make it work all of a sudden, but now I'm sure to run the experiment again myself, just to be sure. In any case, thanks for writing your answer!

Comment: @MaartenBamelis I have checked how exactly `SRWLOCK` behaves and posted an example that shows how things can get bad if `unlock` and `unlock_shared` are misused.

Comment: Thanks for your additional research! Do you have any idea where I could verify whether this is a defect in the standard or not? Is there a place to log these kinds of issues and doubts?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis They have a list of defect reports [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html). I have no experience submitting one. Doesn't mean they will accept it, it is likely they didn't expect any misunderstanding there and assume this is clear.